# Getting from Kochi to Kodanad by public transport

Tags: public-transport, india, kerala

How to get to [Kodanad Elephant Training Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodanad#Activities_with_Elephants) from Fort Kochi (early in the morning) by public transport? I know that there are taxis and tours available but 1000-1200 rupees for such a trip seems a bit too much.

Related - [Where in India can one wash and play with elephants](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5268/where-in-india-can-one-wash-and-play-with-elephants)

Answer (score 4):

From Kochi KSRTC bus stand catch bus to Perumbavoor. From Perumbavoor you will get bus to  Kodanad Elephant Training Center.